# Get aprroximate percentage of jit-compiled code in all code that did run

Tags: java

Is there a simple way to get specified statistics?
For example: some thread was run for 10 seconds total, 4 seconds in jit-compiled code and 6 seconds in interpreted code.

Answer (score -1):

You could use the .wait or .threadSleep command.

Comment: this is completely unrelated to my question

Comment: Please clarify your answer to explain how this solves the specific question, or delete this answer.